# Kinect object recognition

Tags: kinect, openni, object-recognition

I am working on a Kinect project that needs to recognizes flat surface and small objects. I am planning to use openni on a mac machine. So what libraries do I need to used for object recognition? What knowledges do I have to know to finish this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably OpenCV would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to do this in 3D (i.e. using the point cloud from the Kinect), you may find [PCL](http://pointclouds.org) useful. This C++ library has lots of functions for interpreting 3D point cloud data, such as RANSAC plane finding, normal computation, segmentation, feature extraction etc. See the tutorials page [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) for some examples of what can be done.

However, PCL does not contain any machine learning algorithms as yet, so you may wish to make use of some of [those in OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ml._machine_learning.html).

If you are more familiar with MATLAB, you may find it easier to do your work there, as you can process your data one step at a time and easily visualise your results as you go. However, there are fewer built-in 3D processing functions, and it will run much slower than a C++ program.